# Angularjs application is not running in IE. but works fine in chrome

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

My application is built using **ASP.NET** and **angularjs**. It is completely working fine in **Chrome** but in **Internet explorer** it keeps on loading.

Comment: How come we will know without seeing your code ?

Comment: From which IE version you're code is not working? Please paste your code as well.

Comment: your question missing a lot of information. is there any errors in the console? what version of IE are you using? you need to show your code too.

Comment: What is your IE version ? AngularJS doesn't support IE8 and below. It works only for IE9 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the version AngularJS 1.3 then the Team has dropped his support for IE8.

They will support only IE9 and above versions.

For more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie